# How to manually install Octave package socket-1.2.0 on Windows?

Tags: sockets, octave

I try to install socket-1.2.0 without Internet connection. I download from repo and try:

`pkg install sockets-1.2.0.tar.gz`

I get:

```
tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open '/C/s/sockets-1.2.0.tar.gz'
error: called from
   unpack at line 274 column 5
   untar at line 48 column 5
   install at line 81 column 9
   pkg at line 441 column 9
```

As I understand the problems with tar, is there a way to install the package directly from the source, or should I use tar in any case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in tar.exe - is not in PATH

Comment: and the problem with tar.exe was ? and by … ?

Comment: need to add tar.exe in PATH variable. pkg install sockets-1.2.0.tar.gz dont work wihout this

Comment: As a side note perhaps, if you are installing to your main drive you should use the official GNU octave distribution https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/download.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify to get it from octaveforge (IF you have an internet connection).

```
pkg install -forge sockets
```

Note the -forge, and the removal of the version/file extension part.

If you have the tarball downloaded (you will have to download it somehow manually if you don't have an internet connection) on your computer already, then you can run

```
pkg install sockets-1.2.0.tar.gz
```

(Assuming the current octave directory is the same as the downloaded tarball)

Note that the sockets package hasn't been updated for a while and so, depending on what version of octave you are using, may have errors installing.

As a side note on windows, the socket package should have come with the windows install of octave.

If the command

```
pkg list
```

doesn't show 20 or more preinstalled packages, try running

```
pkg rebuild
```

Comment: i cant use  pkg install -forge sockets . coz i get error
error: get_forge_pkg: could not read URL, please verify internet connection
error: called from
    get_forge_pkg at line 66 column 7
    get_forge_download at line 26 column 14
    pkg at line 407 column 31

Comment: I resolved this problem. install and work with octave on VM, not on corporate computer

Comment: If you can not download then you need to manually download the package and use the downloaded tarball part of the answer.

Comment: what version of octave and what directory were you in when running install

Comment: i use portable version 5.1.0 on path: C:\PortableApps\GNUOctavePortable

Comment: and how do you start octave? and did you run the post-install.bat ?

Comment: yes i run this csript. not helped. i run Octave using desktop shortcut

Comment: if you are using the portable version,then you must have created the shortcuts as only the installer version creates them itself - so what is the card in the shortcut that you created?

Comment: also just before trying t install it (from the downloaded version you have) what does running the command:   `ls  sockets-1.2.0.tar.gz` display?

Comment: `>> ls sockets-1.2.0.tar.gz
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is 9A0E-2119

 Directory of C:\s

sockets-1.2.0.tar.gz
               1 File(s)         18 823 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  267 188 310 016 bytes free`

Comment: i try to use Octave with start manually .exe, result is the same

Comment: you should be using the octave.vbs file to start it

Comment: i dont have this file

Comment: where did you download octave from ?